# Duplicity - how to put passphrase in command?

Tags: ssh, gpg, duplicity

I've tried a number of obvious commands as detailed in [Duplicity Man page](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html) to do this but it doesn't seem to work.

**Scenario**

I'm SSH'ing to a machine, then running Duplicity; below is the command, of sorts:-

```
ssh -i /keys/key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@ipAddress "sudo duplicity --s3-european-buckets --s3-use-new-style /local/dir/stuff s3+http://bucket/dir/"
```

Problem is, it's always asking for a passphrase, and I want to run this as an automated process without CLi user replies. The man page's only precise reference is to the environment variable `PASSPHRASE`, but makes little mention (with encrypt-key or sign-key which seem different) how this can be set.

NOTE: It's asking for **GnuPG passphrase**

Comment: Which passphrase is it asking for?

Comment: Added, it's asking for GnuPG

Comment: Why is it asking for a GnuPG passphrase?  It should only need that to decrypt.

Comment: @womble duplicity needs to decrypt previous backups in order to do incremental backups

Comment: @ptman: It didn't when I used to use it.  If it does now, that's a pretty serious regression in, security, useability, *and* resource consumption.

Comment: @ptman Duplicity doesn't need to decrypt previous backups to do incrementals - the reason it is asking for the passphrase is that GPG keys are used for two purposes 1) encryption 2) signatures, and it's the signatures that the passphrase is needed for in this situation. It's best practice to specify a separate key for the signatures with `--sign-key` - without it Duplicity will use the same key for signing and encrypting.

Comment: @Eborbob I stand corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can pass environment variables using [env(1)](http://ss64.com/bash/env.html):

```
env PASSPHRASE=.... duplicity ...
```

Comment: Yes, I cite that in the post. How to set it is the question.

Comment: I see a link added now. Will try... edit/ BINGO!

Answer (score -4):

you are using sudo, so, you need to change options in /etc/sudoers file
[Google Here](https://www.google.ge/search?q=sudo%20don%27t%20ask%20password&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Are you sure, this is GnuPG passphrase yeah? Not an access password for sudo'ing.